# Oddities near Kennedy Parkway

Tags: kennedy-space-center

I'm curious about a couple of things I saw on Google Earth while trying to find the LC-39C (formerly A) site.

Just west of the midpoint of Patrol Road is an unmarked road (edit: it's "A Ave NE" if you get the right zoom level) running almost due south. The south end Google calls "Happy Hammock" Just to the west of this road are a series of rather odd paths:

[28°37'25.5"N 80°40'06.2"W](https://www.google.com/maps/place/28%C2%B037%2725.5%22N+80%C2%B040%2706.2%22W/@28.6241197,-80.6697946,2295m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xac7de1533417252a!8m2!3d28.62375!4d-80.6683889)

There is a similar but less developed set here:

[28°37'43.2"N 80°38'46.6"W](https://www.google.com/maps/place/28%C2%B037%2743.2%22N+80%C2%B038%2746.6%22W/@28.6286667,-80.6484665,1311m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xb08e74bbd2c50580!8m2!3d28.6286667!4d-80.6462778)

And then there's whatever these are:

[28°37'39.9"N 80°39'28.2"W](https://www.google.com/maps/place/28%C2%B037%2739.9%22N+80%C2%B039%2728.2%22W/@28.62775,-80.660022,1311m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xa8d10b8c3e4543c7!8m2!3d28.62775!4d-80.6578333)

Anyone know what this is about?

Comment: Links or screenshots would be nice, to make sure we are looking at the same thing you are. Are you asking about the squiggly features?

Comment: Yes, they look like a go-cart track. The last bits look like something buried at points?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. +1

Comment: Huh.  The Nasca lines of Brevard County.

Comment: Knowing nothing in particular about this and only speculating wildly: is it possible that they are for the purposes of performing controlled burns in the area for vegetation management?

Comment: @Tristan - I don't think so, on two of the paths there appears to be something in the ground at spaced locations, and that something appears to be concrete. Also don't think there's much point in controlled burns in wetland grasses!